# How can server determine whether client is local or remote?

Tags: sockets, tcp, client, server

I'm trying to create a server that is able to determine whether each accepted connection is local or remote.

Server does this:

1. call socket() to create TCP srvsock
2. bind() srvsock to INADDR_ANY|server_port
3. listen() on svrsock
4. accept() connection on svrsock

Local client does this:

1. call socket() to create clisock
2. connect() clisock to 127.0.0.1|server_port

Remote client does this:

1. call socket() to create clisock
2. connect() clisock to server_public_ip|server_port

When accept() returns, how can the server determine whether the client is local or remote?

Answer (score 0):

The server can use `getpeername()` to get the address of a connected client.  Or use the address that `accept()` outputs.  Either way, if that address is among the addresses returned by `getifaddrs()` (or equivalent function, depending on your platform) then the client is local; otherwise, it is remote.

Comment: Instead of using getifaddrs() and cycling through its addresses looking for a match, could I simply bind local clients to 127.0.0.1 before calling connect()? If so then it seems like the server would only need to check for 127.0.0.1 returned by accept().

Comment: Local clients can bind to 127.0.0.1 before connecting to ensure that the server sees that as the peer address.  If that's how you identify local clients, however, then that's effectively a *definition* of "local".  If it would present a problem for a client running on the same machine as the server to connect to the server via a non-loopback address (or a different loopback address), and thereby fail to be recognized as "local", then it is unsafe to proceed as you propose.